# How to fetch array objects from api using axios?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, api, axios

1. Im fetching data from api using axios.
2. I have array of objects.
3. I would like to fetch objects inside array.

Here is api : https://51fgc922b7.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/productpreview?product_id=122003
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zavy.jpg)

Here is what i tried !

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.product_id) {
      axios.
        get(`https://51fgc922b7.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/productpreview?product_id=${props.product_id}`)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data)
          setModelData(res.data.data[0])
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setIsErrorImage(true)
        })
    }
  }, []);
```

Im able to fetch data but what im trying to achive is that, there are three objects with camera objects called 0,1,2 and i want to fetch them.

Comment: It's not clear to me what isn't working in the code shown.  You state that you're able to fetch data, so what is failing?  `setModelData` *looks like* a state hook setter function, and so would be updating the component state to include the data you're looking for.  Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: Im able to fetch data @David. But i have objects inside data. If you look into api which i posted. I have 0,1,2 objects with camera values, I want to fetch them as well but confused how to get them and use.

Comment: Are you just asking how to access nested properties/elements in an object in JavaScript?  (If so then it sounds like you're trying to run before learning how to walk.)  If `res.data.data[0]` contains the information you want then your updated state has the information you want.  What prevents you from using that data?  In the code shown, what is *actually failing* in some way?  Being "confused on how to use it" isn't really a specific question about the code/technology involved.  Please clarify.

Comment: Please  include some more relevant code or a minimal reproducible example, community members  will be able to understand the problem better

Comment: Yes @david. My confusion is, how to access nested properties. res.data.data[0] contains all the data i need and im able to use them in the component. This is how im able to distribute useState stored data "modelData.model_url". As you right said i want to access objects inside array.

Comment: @PavanKulkarni: Then it sounds like what you're looking for are introductory tutorials to JavaScript.  `res.data.data[0]` is already an example of how to access nested properties/elements in an object.  You're accessing the `res` variable, which has a property called `data`, which is an object, which also has a property called `data`, which is an array, and you're accessing the first element of that array.  It honestly sounds like you've essentially copied/pasted this code from somewhere and don't understand what it is or does, and are asking us to just write more code for you...

Comment: Im beginner @David.

Comment: @PavanKulkarni: And everyone here can certainly appreciate that.  Everyone was a beginner at some point.  But you need to take the time to learn the fundamentals.  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

console.log(res.data) if correct ,

> setModelData(res.data)

and in return  example ;

```
modelData.map((item)=> {
return (
<div> {item.camera.map((data)=>{
return (
<div> {data.camera_beta} </div>
)
})}
 </div>  )})
```

this is what i want to tell

```
const [modelData, setModelData] = useState([
  {
    name: 'Electronics',
    slug: 'electronics',
    count: 11,
    items: [
      { name: 'Phones', slug: 'phones', count: 4 },
      { name: 'Tablets', slug: 'tablets', count: 5 },
      { name: 'Laptops', slug: 'laptops', count: 2 },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Clothing',
    slug: 'clothing',
    count: 12,
    items: [
      { name: 'Tops', slug: 'tops', count: 3 },
      { name: 'Shorts', slug: 'shorts', count: 4 },
      { name: 'Shoes', slug: 'shoes', count: 5 },
    ],
  }
 ])
```

you have data like this.
this way you set the data into setmodeldata in useeffect. 
in useffect after set

console.log(modelData) and
console.log(modelData[0])

you can see the difference between the two.one comes in the form of an object and the other as an array.

at most you can map them

Comment: I have tried this, Am wrong here ? camera2.beta = modelData.camera[1].camera.beta;
    camera2.alpha = modelData.camera[1].camera.alpha;
    camera2.radius = modelData.camera[1].radius;

Comment: I wanted to give a little more detail . I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your requirement but as far as I understood you just want the array of objects from the data you get. You can get that simply by traversing the object like

```
const cameraData = res.data.reduce((acc,el) => [...acc, ...el.camera], [] )
```